# Check if a string variable is empty in batch script

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I am trying to write a batch script to get a string in a variable and check if it is empty, and if it is empty then it is directed to a loop. The below code represents the problem

```
:loop
set /p cide=
IF NOT "a%1"=="a" (set cide="%1")
IF [%1]==[] goto loop
ELSE
echo IDE entered
TIMEOUT 5 > NUL
```

The program starts to loop again even if i give a string.

I tried to put `IF [%cide%]==[] goto loop` or `IF %cide%==[] goto loop` it gave an error stating "ELSE" not recognized.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `if not defined cide goto loop`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try something like that :

```dos
@echo off
:loop
cls & Color 0A
echo Type what you want !
set /p "cide="
IF "%cide%"=="" ( 
    Cls & Color 0C
    echo You must enter something
    Timeout /T 2 /NoBreak>nul
    goto loop
) ELSE (
    Goto Next
)

:Next
Cls
echo %cide% is entered
pause
```

Comment: Thanks @Hackoo, this worked. I tried the same but with different structure from what have you written, it gave either error or exits out. Very thanks man!!!

Answer (score 6):

```
@echo off
:loop
cls & Color 0A
echo Type what you want !
set /p "cide="
IF [%cide%]==[] (
     Cls & Color 0C
     echo You must enter something
     choice /d y /t 2 > nul
     goto loop              
) ELSE (
     Goto Next
 )

:Next
Cls
echo %cide% is entered
pause
```

Comment: Any insight when using [] is better than quotes in the check ?